# How can I dynamically set style of a mapped element without using inline styling?

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I'm coding a React function with parent component containing an array of objects:

```
let const ingredients = [
    {name:"lettuce",color:"green"},
    {name:"tomato",color:"red"}
]
```

...

In a child component, there is a map function that breaks down an array to single items to be displayed in a div.

What is the best practice for defining CSS styling for an object `className:"name"` to set `backgroundColor: {ingredient.color};`? I'm trying to avoid manual entry of the entire set of key/values of 'ingredients', to allow updating the object without breaking the code.

I'm currently using inline styling, which I have been advised against. Currently using:

```
let burg = props.toppings.map((item) => {
const divColor = {backgroundColor: item.color};
return (<div style={divColor}>{item.name}</div>)
```

Comment: is there any particular reason why don't want to use inline style?

Comment: Simply my TA (who has a pretty good resume) advised, as a rule, against using inline styling.

Answer (score 1):

Inline style is bad when you have other solution to do what you want. Here, you have a string that is the color (red, green, etc.) so you could write a css class for every color, but that is of course a really bad idea. Inline style is the good way to do it here.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting the class of the div instead of the style. That way you can change the look without resorting to inlining the style.

You could create a css class for lettuce with the background color green, instead of using the `item.color` you'd set `class={ item.name }`

Comment: So if there is hundreds of items, you'll have to create hundreds of classes. Bad idea

Comment: That's a fair point. Rereading the question, and given that it's only the color that is going to differ between items, inline style will probably be the best solution. If there are more differences that are going to be styled I would probably still go with classes, especially if they can be categorized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way.

css can be more handy if you use scss

```
// css
.color-green {
  color: green;
}
.color-red {
  color: red;
}
```

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const ingredients = [
  { name: "lettuce", color: "green" },
  { name: "tomato", color: "red" }
];
const Vegetable = ({ color, text }) => {
  return (
    <p>
      this is <span className={`color-${color}`}>{text}</span> color{" "}
    </p>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {ingredients.map((item, index) => {
        return <Vegetable key={index} color={item.color} text={item.name} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```